# Comparing Events to Screen Views in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I recently asked about comparing two events in Google Analytics ([Comparing Events in Google Analytics](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39900/comparing-events-in-google-analytics)).  I have another issue now involving events.

I'd like to compare screen views to events for my iOS application.

For example, in my application you can perform actions on an image, generally revolving around sharing.  Thus, I have the following events:

```
Category  Action     Label      Meaning
--------  ------     -----      ----------------------------------------------
Activity  Abandoned  <NULL>     Share button clicked, activity not selected
Activity  Abandoned  Facebook   Facebook sharing selected, activity cancelled
Activity  Completed  Twitter    Twitter sharing selected, activity completed
```

These aren't the only events; just examples.

I also have a Custom Dimension: Image

What I'd like is to see a report that shows me the number of Screen Views by Image as well as Total Events where `Event Category == "Activity"` including (and in this case I'm particularly interested in) those images where there are a lot of screen views and no activity events.

I can compare screen views and total events for all images that have at least one activity; however, I can't figure out how to say, "give me the total events for these images where category is activity OR give me a 0 if there were no events."

In fact, I'm not really sure how I could produce a report of all of the images where there are no events matching a criteria, let alone just the total number of events including 0 when there aren't matches.

How does one go about doing this?

Comment: did you eventually figure this out?

Comment: No, sorry. But I️ also haven’t tried since around the time I️ posted the question. :(